# One way binding on AngularJS with a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'll try to explain what I'm trying to achieve. In a form I have a generic filter, let's say, languages.

Then I have sections which, by default, inherit that filter but they can change it per section. When the filter updates, a service will fetch some content and show it to the user. However, if the generic filter change, it should propagate down to the generic ones.

We had that with jQuery in the controller which wasn't great, nor the "*Angular Way™*" so I decided to refactor it with a directive:

```
app.directive('oneWayBind', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        priority: 500,
        scope: {
            oneWayBind : '='
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            var updateValue = function () {
                if (scope.oneWayBind !== ngModel.$modelValue){
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.oneWayBind);
                }
            };

            updateValue();

            var unwatch = scope.$watch('oneWayBind', updateValue);

            // Cleaning up
            scope.$on('$destroy', unwatch);
        }
    };
});
```

This *seems* to be working. However, it won't reflect the value on the input when the model is updated. I've prepared a plnkr showing the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/PGGJJ5YS3SrvOcaHPAWB?p=preview

As you may see in the text, the value is updated succesfully, and if you start typing on the first input, the text and the input below **will update**. However, if you change the global one (third input), it **won't be reflected** on the first one.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not being sure at 100% of what you want to accomplish here, but I if I understand correctly, all you want is to update the DOM when the model changes. If so, you missed a `ngModel.$render();` after updating the `ngModel`. You need to do that because that is how you trigger a DOM update when the `ngModel` changes.

See here: http://plnkr.co/edit/skT4Gc3OkQc6QcOixiZK?p=preview

Is that what you want to achieve?